# Is it possible in PIG to create column field by defining column field value

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hiveql

Suppose i have below Structured data file

1298712012061228765236542123049824234209374
1203972012073042198531203948203498023498023
1203712012092329385612350924395798456892345
1234812012101223423498230482034893204820398

Here in above file first 6 digit are UserId from (1-6) next 8 digit are year_date from (7-12) column next 6 column is Count field from (13-18) , then similarly I have product_id from (19-30) and Character_values column from (31-42) for the above flat file, So I want my data in below format. I mean to say is that I want to load my data using this mentioned field. Is there any option available in PIG or HIVE for this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it both in pig and hive. Two solutions are below
**PIG:**

```
data = LOAD '/data.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (line);
strsplit = FOREACH data GENERATE 
SUBSTRING(line,1,6) AS UserID,
SUBSTRING(line,7,12) AS year_date,
SUBSTRING(line,13,18) AS Count,
SUBSTRING(line,19,30) AS product_id,
SUBSTRING(line,31,42) AS Character_values;
```

When you dump :
dump strsplit;
(29871,29871,29871,29871,29871)
(20397,20397,20397,20397,20397)
(20371,20371,20371,20371,20371)
(23481,23481,23481,23481,23481)

**HIVE:**

Step1:create a temp table and load the original data;

```
create table temp(line String)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
LOAD DATA INPATH '/data.txt' INTO TABLE temp;
```

Step2:create a table which will fit your data.

```
   create table user(UserID String,year_date String,Count String,product_id String,Character_values String)
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Step3:Inster you temp table into actula table

```
INSERT INTO TABLE user
SELECT substr(line,0,6),substr(line,7,12),substr(line,13,18),substr(line,19,30),substr(line,31,42)FROM temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you use SUBSTRING?

```
A = LOAD 'DATA' USING PigStorage() AS (line); 
B = FOREACH A GENERATE SUBSTRING(line,1,6) AS UserID, SUBSTRING(line,7,12) AS Year_date ...
```